# How to get response from ajax after selecting the auto completing email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies, autocomplete

I have a code to check email id is available or not in the database using ajax on keypress. If email Id is available then submit button will enable or email id is not available in the database then submit button will show disabled.
I have no issue in above process below code is working for above process.

My issue is some time users are getting the popup to store the username and password in the browser when the user entered the username and password. I am talking about cookies or can say auto-filed data. For example: If you enter the email id two or three times in text field then next time you clicked on the field you will automatically get your email.

Same issue I am getting. I saved the username and password on my browser and now I am selecting my username and clicking the button which is not working because I am using ajax on keypress. I f I type the email then it is working If I select the email then not working. I need if any user selects the email id than also button should active.

Hope you understand my issue .would you help me in this issue?

**On keypress Getting ajax response**

[image]

**Auto filling the email the no response from ajax**

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form action="" method="POST">

<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="text_field" /> 
<span id="email-validation-error" class="error"></span> 

<input id="submitYesNo" type="submit" name="next" value="submit" disabled="disabled"> 
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 


/*checking email id is already exist or not*/ 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true); 
}); 

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
var elem = $("#id"); //assign target element with id 

$("input[name='email']").on('keyup',function() 
{ 
var email = $('#email').val(); 
$.ajax( 
{ 
url:'process.php', 
type:'POST', 
data:'email='+email, 
success:function(data) 
{ 
if (data == "success") { 
$("#submitYesNo").prop('disabled', false); 
$("#email-validation-error").html(data); 
} 
else{ 
$("#email-validation-error").html(data); 
$("#submitYesNo").prop('disabled', true); 
} 
}, 

}); 
}); 
}); 

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
 if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$email;

    $query="SELECT Email FROM `request` WHERE Email='".$email."'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    $search_record=$result->num_rows;

    if ($search_record > 0) {
     echo "success";
          }
        else{
         echo "Email does not exist, please sign up to use our services";
        }   


}
```

Comment: add keyup with blur in `on` function in your jquery or else you can turn off the autocomplete in your input field like `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Fairy Dancer, Can you please help me with an example?

Comment: Turn off autocomplete in email field `<input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" class="text_field" />` **OR** turn off autocomplete for whole form `<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: its better to set autocomplete="off"

Comment: If I set autocomplete off. and any user saved their username and password on the browser then it will work?

Comment: Let me tell you one think. My email and password are stored in the browser. Whenever I am checking my site my email id is auto displaying in the field of the email but when  I am clicking the next button then nothing is happing Because that is not calling my ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will work when the user click or focus outside of that input field otherwise it wont work

```
$("input[name='email']").bind('change keyup', function(){
     console.log(this.value);
});
```

Check this once it may help on your scenario

Comment: It's not working for me. My email and password are stored in the browser. Whenever I am checking my site my email id is auto displaying in the field of the email but when I am clicking the next button then nothing is happing Because that is not calling my ajax. If I type my email the it is working

Comment: then change that ajax call on button click [ the next button ]. So whenever the button clicked it will execute the ajax call and validate your process.

Comment: Mr. Fairy. I tried our code. I remove  the keyup and just added your code and working, I just want to know why you use      console.log(this.value);

Comment: Cool!! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Bind blur event with keyup event.So that when your textbox loose focus at that time your ajax can be called again

```
$("input[name='email']").on('keyup blur',function() // Add blur event
{
```

Comment: Mr.B. Desai,  If any user selects the autocomplete his/her email then Ajax will work?